# Hibernate query returned list with null values

Tags: java, hibernate, list, null

Why does this HQL return list with `null` values?

```
SELECT a FROM CustomerGroup a 
INNER JOIN FETCH a.customer b 
WHERE a.merchant.merchantId = :merchantId
AND b.status = :status
```

I found none of the rows is `null` when I check againts the database.

```
    customer_id | merchant_id | data
    ------------+-------------+----------
           5751 |        1208 |  
           5338 |        1208 |  
           5339 |        1208 |  
           5349 |        1208 |
```

This is the list returned by the HQL:

```
[null, com.company.dto.CustomerGroup@70872f1c, com.company.dto.CustomerGroup@38489b4b, com.company.dto.CustomerGroup@4b063eda]
```

I need some clue to fix this, anybody please. Thank you.

Comment: Are you certain that the results of your query really represent what Hibernate queried?

Comment: Yes, the list was returned by the HQL. How do you think?

Comment: No, what I'm asking is are you certain that the table actually had the 4 records you showed us at the moment Hibernate was doing the query?  It seems to me that there could somehow have been a `NULL` in there when the HQL was being executed.

Comment: I don't see how this is possible. Hibernate can't return null instead of entity instance. Could be that the list is initialized to a size bigger than the result set, and the remaining items are displayed as null. If you iterate through the list, do you actually get nulls? What does the `list.size()` return?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The list written above was the list when HQL is executed, there was no modification (insert or delete) on the table at that time. 

@PredragMaric Yes, the `list.size()` returned 4 with first data `null`.